# accessing pyqt5 resources from non-PyQt5 objects

Tags: python, qt, resources, pyqt5

I would like to use the PyQt5 / Qt5 resource system from non-PyQt or non-Qt objects. For example I would like to include some test DICOM files as resources and then use pydicom to open the resource DICOM files from the imported resources module instead of providing them in a separate folder with my application.

Does anyone know if it is possible to access the resource objects inside of the resources.py module generated using the pyrcc5 utility fromnon PyQt5 / Qt5 object similar to the following

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * # import PyQt5 modules required

import resources              # resource module generated using pyrcc5
import dicom as dcm           # PyDicom

icon = QIcon(":/icon.png")    # This works!

ds = dcm.read_file(":/my_test_dicom_file.dcm") # This does not work!
```

Thank you for any pointers to the correct process or documentation.

Comment: It looks like `dcm.read_file` can also take a file-like object. So read the resource using a `QFile` and then create an `io.BytesIO` object from the data.

Comment: python2: `cStringIO.StringIO`, python3: `io.BytesIO`

Comment: I'm rather new to PyQt. Can you give me an example on how you would do this. It appears that whenreading the file from the QFile I end up with an empty byte string.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get that to work. I see what is going on now. Out of curiosity...do you know of a python based resource system that is similar to the Qt system but without the Qt  dependency.

Comment: The resources are (optionally) compressed and stored in the *resource_rc.py* module as a simple byte-string. It would be very easy to write your own code to do something similar using whatever compression algorithm you liked (e.g. [zlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html#module-zlib)). However, doing things this way will lose the one real advantage of using rcc, which is its seamless integration with a wide range of qt apis. I doubt whether there's much to be gained from a third-party/hand-rolled solution.